# D3 zoom - Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm following [this tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708) to learn how to zoom an svg. Here is my code.

```js
var vis = d3.select("#svg-canvas").append("svg")
  .attr("width", "550")
  .attr("height", "400")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "svg-container")
  .attr("transform", "translate(550,400)")
  .call(zoom);

vis.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .style("fill", "#444");

var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

function zoomed() {
  d3.select(".svg-container").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-canvas">

</div>
```

But i'm getting an error in the console which says the following

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined` .

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use .call(zoom), your variable zoom is undefined.

It should be defined first.

```js
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
  .scaleExtent([1, 10])
  .on("zoom", zoomed);

var vis = d3.select("#svg-canvas").append("svg")
  .attr("width", "550")
  .attr("height", "400")
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "svg-container")
  .attr("transform", "translate(550,400)")
  .call(zoom);

vis.append("rect")
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .attr("width", 100)
  .attr("height", 40)
  .style("fill", "#444");

function zoomed() {
  d3.select(".svg-container").attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="svg-canvas">

</div>
```